# Magento Cannot re-index 'Rebuild Catalog product fulltext search index'

Tags: magento

In my magento system when I try to reindex the 'Catalog Search Index' I get 'Cannot initialize the indexer process.'

I was wondering if anyone knows what this might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the var/log folder for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-index like here :

[Magento mass reindexing gives internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076695/magento-mass-reindexing-gives-internal-server-error)

And if it don't work , you could try to remove all file in

> path/to/your/project/folder/var/locks/