# Magento mass reindexing gives internal server error

Tags: php, magento, reindex

How can we reindex a Magento 1.7.02 version site having more than 24,000 products and  hundreds of categories?

When I try to reindex the product price index in Magento Admin Index Management, it generates an internal Server Error 500. When I checked the server log for errors it shows up with messages:

```
home2/mysitete/public_html/403.shtml
[Wed Jun 04 22:15:03 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] client denied by server configuration: /home2/mysitete/public_html/ultimate4wheel/app/etc/local.xml
[Wed Jun 04 22:14:37 2014] [error] [client 202.191.65.162] File does not exist: /home2/mysitete/public_html/404.shtml
[Wed Jun 04 22:14:37 2014] [error] [client 202.191.65.162] File does not exist: /home2/mysitete/public_html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 04 22:14:36 2014] [error] [client 202.191.65.162] File does not exist: /home2/mysitete/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://mysitetest.com.au/ultimate4wheel/index.php/admin/process/edit/process/4/key/e7cfe1aaf5b456e018f28e488e42a4bd/
[Wed Jun 04 22:13:51 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] File does not exist: /home2/mysitete/public_html/403.shtml
[Wed Jun 04 22:13:51 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] client denied by server configuration: /home2/mysitete/public_html/ultimate4wheel/app/etc/local.xml
[Wed Jun 04 22:13:48 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] File does not exist: /home2/mysitete/public_html/403.shtml
[Wed Jun 04 22:13:48 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] client denied by server configuration: /home2/mysitete/public_html/ultimate4wheel/app/etc/local.xml
[Wed Jun 04 22:13:43 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] File does not exist: /home2/mysitete/public_html/403.shtml
[Wed Jun 04 22:13:43 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] client denied by server configuration: /home2/mysitete/public_html/ultimate4wheel/app/etc/local.xml
[Wed Jun 04 22:13:35 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] File does not exist: /home2/mysitete/public_html/403.shtml
[Wed Jun 04 22:13:35 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] client denied by server configuration: /home2/mysitete/public_html/ultimate4wheel/app/etc/local.xml
[Wed Jun 04 22:13:21 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] File does not exist: /home2/mysitete/public_html/403.shtml
[Wed Jun 04 22:13:21 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] client denied by server configuration: /home2/mysitete/public_html/ultimate4wheel/app/etc/local.xml
[Wed Jun 04 22:12:06 2014] [error] [client 101.0.79.114] File does not exist: /home2/mysitete/public_html/403.sht
```

Can anyone help me to solve it... or reindex correctly?

I have also tried increasing time limit, memory limit, skipping security, etc. but didn't work as I wrote in .htaccess file:

```
   php_value memory_limit 2836M
   php_value max_execution_time 2592000
   php_value max_input_time 2592000
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 864000
   php_value session.cookie_lifetime 864000
   php_value max_input_vars 50000
```

Answer (score 2):

For mass re-indexing you should always try command prompt.

Go to your project path through command line:

```
cd path/to/your/project/folder
```

And then open "Shell" folder

```
cd shell
```

And then do the following command to re-index all indexes.

```
php indexer.php --reindexall
```

For more info go through this [**link**](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/re-indexing-magento-command-line/).

[Magento link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/332176/)